# How do I get all different lists all in the same order?

Tags: python, list

I have a list from 1 to 6, `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and i want to get a list that contains the following 6 lists:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[2,3,4,5,6,1]
[3,4,5,6,1,2]
[4,5,6,1,2,3]
[5,6,1,2,3,4]
[6,1,2,3,4,5]
```

So all 6 different lists that have the same order.

I'm too bad at coding to do this myself and i would also like to know if there is perhaps a function that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[i:] + lst[:i])
```

Prints:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks alot. Very clever. Im going to go ahead and try to udnerstand what on earth is going on in this code. But at least it works so i can continue now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you like using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
start = np.arange(1,7)
result = [np.roll(start, -i).tolist() for i in range(6)]
```

gives you:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
 [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in a:
    
    k = 1
    res = a[k:]
    res.append(a[0])
    a = res
   
    print(res)
```

Result:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```